# Frontend. Как реализовать блок?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Нужно чтобы при нажатии на цифры, выделенные красным, менялся контент, выделенный зеленым. 
Только начинаю свой путь в верстке, подскажите с помощью чего (какого языка или конструкции) можно реализовать?
Если у кого есть пример похожий, тоже с радостью посмотрю.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону слайдеров или табов

Comment: Это классический вопрос про табы. Тут на него отвечали уже много раз. Воспользуйтесь поиском.

Comment: Благодарю, теперь хоть знаю как это называется)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

С табами будет попроще, т.к. они сами по себе простые.

Вот такой вариант написал.
Для работы табов используется библиотека `Jquery`

```js
$('.tab .tab-selector .item').on('click', function(){
  if(!$(this).hasClass('active')) { // Определяем, что нажатая вкладка НЕ является активной.
    let thisIndex = $(this).index(); // Определяем какая по счёту кнопка нажата.
    // "перевешиваем" класс active
    $('.tab-selector .item.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    // Далее определяем какой слайд будет равен переменной, в которой содержится индекс нажатой кнопки.
    let thisSlide = $('.tab .tab-content .slide').eq(thisIndex); // Запишем в переменную
    // "перевешаем" класс active и слайдам
    $('.tab-content .slide.active').removeClass('active');
    thisSlide.addClass('active');
  }
});
```

```css
.tab {width: 360px;}

.tab-selector {display: block; width: 100%; height: 40px; font-size: 0; margin-bottom: 20px;}
.tab-selector .item {display: inline-block; width: 40px; height: 40px; line-height: 40px; text-align: center; border: 2px solid #000; color: #000; box-sizing: border-box; cursor: pointer; position: relative; margin-right: 40px; font-size: 15px;}
.tab-selector .item::before {content: '•••••'; display: block; width: 40px; height: 40px; line-height: 40px; text-align: center; position: absolute; right: -42px;
top: -2px; color: red; letter-spacing: 2px; pointer-events: none;}
.tab-selector .item:last-child {margin-right: 0;}
.tab-selector .item:last-child::before {display: none;}
.tab-selector .item.active {border-color: red; color: red;}
.tab-selector .item:hover {border-color: red;}


.tab-content {display: block; width: 100%;}
.tab-content .slide {display: none; width: 100%;}
.tab-content .slide.active {display: block;}

.slide::after {content: ''; display: block; clear: both;}
.slide .left, .slide .right {display: inline-block; width: 50%; float: left;}

.slide .left h2, .slide .left p {display: block; padding: 0; margin: 0;}
.slide .left h2::after {content: ''; display: block; width: 40%; height: 4px; background: red; margin: 5px 0;}

.slide .right img {width: 100%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="tab">
  <div class="tab-selector">
    <div class="item active">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="slide active">
      <div class="left">
        <h2>Заголовок 1</h2>
        <p>Описание</p>
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x250?text=Slide 1">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <div class="left">
        <h2>Заголовок 2</h2>
        <p>Описание</p>
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x250?text=Slide 2">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <div class="left">
        <h2>Заголовок 3</h2>
        <p>Описание</p>
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x250?text=Slide 3">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <div class="left">
        <h2>Заголовок 4</h2>
        <p>Описание</p>
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x250?text=Slide 4">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <div class="left">
        <h2>Заголовок 5</h2>
        <p>Описание</p>
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x250?text=Slide 5">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Благодарю вас за подробнейший ответ!

Comment: Минусовать могут все, а обосновать минус никто не может.. Ужс, а не люди.

Answer (score 0):

Это классическая задача использования табов. 
Можешь использовать например jquery tabs.
Но если js пока нет возможности изучать, есть вариант адаптировать к задаче прием верстки слайдера на чистом css
Что-нибудь типа http://www.sitehere.ru/slajdery-na-chistom-css-bonusnyj-slajder

Comment: Благодарю, js пока поверхностно изучал, обязательно посмотрю.

Answer (score -1):

Вот пример кода.

А [по это ссылке](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/default.asp) найдешь массу решений для вопросов, которые возникают у новичков.

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```css
body {font-family: Arial;}

/* Style the tab */
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}

/* Style the close button */
.topright {
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 28px;
}

.topright:hover {color: red;}
```

```html
<h2>Tabs</h2>
<p>Click on the x button in the top right corner to close the current tab:</p>

<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')" id="defaultOpen">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="topright">&times</span>
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="topright">&times</span>
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="topright">&times</span>
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Все попробую, спасибо за подробный ответ!